# How to run a console application from QT GUI application in android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I have the following situation: an application based on Qt Widgets which is the interface to run a console application in the background. It works well on Windows and Linux and now I'm compiling it for Android. I compiled the console application (written in C) using the NDK (android-NDK-R10b). To compile the interface I used qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.3.0. I tried to include the console application in the assets in the main application and in the first beginning of the app copy it for running folder using this code:

```
QFile file;
file.setFileName("assets:/ConsoleApp");
if (!QFile::exists("./ConsoleApp"))
{
    if (File.Copy("./ConsoleApp"))
        qDebug () << "File copied";
    else
        qDebug () << "File not copied";
}
else
    qDebug () << "The file already exists";
```

and then run it with QProcess. The file is copied well but try to run it returns the QProcess::FailedToStart error.

I tried to run it using Android Terminal Emulator from a folder on the internal storage and it does not run. Then it occurred to me to try to run it from SD card and it worked perfectly from the Terminal Emulator and from the Qt application.

This solution not help me, I need to run it with Qt from somewhere in the internal storage because not all devices have SD card. How I can solve this problem?

PD: Sorry for any error in mi English.

Comment: Hi @JoséAndrés, have you come up with a solution?

Comment: I did not find a solution to the problem. Apparently Android did not allow me to run the console program from another application in Qt.

Comment: You should use full path to access the file not relative paths. The copied file may not have execute permissions and the OS will not allow running of applications that does not have the execute bit set. Alternatively, if the file is a shell script then you can use "/bin/sh" to launch it, e.g. "/bin/sh /sdcard/ConsoleApp". Note that the solution would need to comply with Android Scope Storage restrictions introduced in Android 10.